# How can I increase the height of a basic-widget and a belonging vertical layout when I add other widgets to the basic-widget using Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I've got a "basic-widget" that has a vertical layout. Into this layout, I want to add other widgets by clicking on a push-button (This works). For every added widget, I would like the "basic-widget" and the layout to increase in height of the added widget. This last step doesn't work. Instead, the added widgets get smaller in height by adding more of them to the "basic-widget" and the layout.

I tried following code:

```
void own_widget::on_add_tbm_pb_clicked()
{
    tbm_widget *new_tbm_widget = new tbm_widget(this);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(new_tbm_widget);
    this->setGeometry(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height()+100);// own_widget should grow by adding new tbm_widgets
    QRect layout_geometry(this->x(), this->y()+60, this->width(), this->height()-100);//set corresponding geometry for layout
    ui->verticalLayout->setGeometry(layout_geometry);// putting geometry onto layout

    new_tbm_widget->setGeometry(this->x(),this->y()+60+tbm_listposition*110, 400, 100);
    new_tbm_widget->show();
    
    tbm_list.append(new_tbm_widget);
    tbm_listposition ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't play with geometry of layouts. Layouts will handle resizing operations. That's what they are made for. Just add widgets to layout.

```
void own_widget::on_add_tbm_pb_clicked()
{
    tbm_widget *new_tbm_widget = new tbm_widget(this);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(new_tbm_widget);
    
    tbm_list.append(new_tbm_widget);
}
```

If your layout still not resize them, maybe you forgot to set the layout. Or your size policy might be fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll try adding the widgets to the basic-widgets without the layout just with resizing the basic-widget.

Comment: I highly suggest you to not to do that. If you provide more code of `tbm_widget` and `own_widget`, I am pretty sure, me or somebody else would find a more elegant solution.